# MongoDb Aggregation lookup nested Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Lets say I have a MongoDB collection with docs like:

```
{
    _id,
    name: "someName",
    children:[
        ObjectId,
        ObjectId,
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to to a deep nest with child using the aggregation framework and lookup? Another problem is that we do not often know what the lookup field of the child is going to be, therefore the child has a "Lookup" array with the fields that should be looked up in the database.

So for example, the result would be with a depth of 3:

```
{
    _id,
    name: "someName",
    children:[
        {
            _id,
            name: "someName",
            children:[
                {
                    _id,
                    name: "someName",
                    children:[
                        ObjectId,
                        ObjectId,
                    ]
                }
                {
                    _id,
                    name: "someName",
                    children:[
                        ObjectId,
                        ObjectId,
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            _id,
            name: "someName",
            children:[
                ObjectId,
                ObjectId,
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to be able to create a function that enables me to specify the "depth" of the lookup.

We are using the mongodb NodeJs driver.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 solutions here:

1. To change your schema and try to use nested sets pattern. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-nested-sets/
2. To make a recursive function to fetch all data you need, but you will face a problem such as N-aggregation method calls

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestions! The first solution is not suitable, since we have a graph structure, not a tree structure. But that was another clear from the example I have, so that is my bad. I will look into the second and make something custom!